# Why a matrix with a low entropy will be sparser?

Tags: information-theory

The entropy of a matrix $\mathbf{P}$:
$$H(\mathbf{P})=-\sum_{i j} \mathbf{P}_{i j} \log \mathbf{P}_{i j}$$

Why a matrix with low entropy will be sparser, and with high entropy will be smoother?

Comment: Is ${\bf P}$ a row-stochastic matrix?

Comment: The question as stated makes little sense , if P has a single very big element its "entropy"  would be greater than a small smooth matrix. There must be some normalization involved, I guesss either the sum of elements is one or the sum of rows/columns. Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, for the evaluation of the entropy:

$$0 \log(0) = 1 \log(1) = 0.$$

While in general

$$x \log(x) > 0,$$

for $x \in (0, 1)$.

Then:

- ${\bf P}_{ij} = 0$ stands for a zero entry of the matrix ${\bf P}$, then the higher is the number of ${\bf P}_{ij} = 0$, the sparser ${\bf P}$ will be;
- Since ${\bf P}$ is row-stochastic, ${\bf P}_{ij} = 1$ stands for row composed by one "1" entry, and all others are "0"; again, this is related to the sparsity of the matrix.